# redirecting a survey user to last page that he/she was on

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have been working on a survey and I am almost done, but there's one requirement that has really eaten me up.

A user can take a survey, and there are 6 different sets of questions and each set of questions is in a question group from 1-6. When a user does question group 1-4 and logs out, he/she should log back in and get redirected to question group 5. So far my code is working and redirecting to the first three pages (questions1.php, people.php and environment.php), but refusing for the rest.

I think the problem is my if elseif statement. Any help to achieve the desired result would really be appreciated. Cheers!

Here is the code

```
if ($row['userid']==$user){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
if($row['question_group_id']==1 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("location:people.php"); 
       }
elseif($row['question_group_id']==2 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("Location:environment.php"); 
    }
elseif($row['question_group_id']==3 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("Location:widerorganization.php"); 
   }
elseif($row['question_group_id']==4 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("Location:procurement.php"); 
  }
elseif($row['question_group_id']==5 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("Location: communication.php"); 
   }
elseif($row['question_group_id']==6 && $row['choosen']==1){
 header("Location: notificationpage.php"); 
    }}}
 else {
 header("Location:questions1.php"); 
    }
```

Comment: also note that after `header()` some code might still be executed. To prevent this add `exit();` after each `header()`

Comment: You are using `$row` outside your `while` statement, then you're overwriting it, and using it again at the last `elseif`.

Comment: Hi Dave, the formatting of your question could really do with a bit of TLC, would make it easier for us to help you!

Comment: @SebastianTroy , lol..cool...

Comment: @vonUbisch i just saw that..on the last elseif i have gotten rid of the row for 'userid'..I put the userid which is outside the loop inside the loop but that makes the code worse..its not even checking anything but going direct to questions1.php which is the else

Comment: @SuperDJ when i use exit(); it immediately stops at the first if and redirects me to that first location

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code, because without it I cannot fabricate an exact answer because of too many uncertainties due to overwriting.

Comment: how do i update?not seeing the option for that  :( @vonUbisch

Comment: For some reason editting is disabled on this question.. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @vonUbisch i just udated the question, the code part...i removed $row['userid']==$user in the last else if

Comment: @DaveSari check out my answer below ;)

Comment: @DaveSari, `mysql_fetch_assoc` always returns one row, right?

Comment: @vonUbisch yes it does thats why i included the while loop so as for it to loop..

Comment: So what's there to loop then? If it's only one row you can leave out the `while` loop, but it does not matter that much..

Comment: @vonUbisch initially i had no loop but without the loop it just checked the first condition if its true and load that page, with the loop its able to check more than the first condition..or maybe its what i used, is there a possibility of using a case statement? so that it checks all the condition before loading a page

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of rendering clean codes.

I just reformatted your code. Here's your code before:

```
if ($row['userid']==$user)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set))
    {
        if ($row['question_group_id']==1 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("location:people.php");
        }
        else if($row['question_group_id']==2 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("Location:environment.php"); 
        }
        else if ($row['question_group_id']==3 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("Location:widerorganization.php");
        }
        else if ($row['question_group_id']==4 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("Location:procurement.php"); 
        }
        else if ($row['question_group_id']==5 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("Location: communication.php");
        }
        else if ($row['question_group_id']==6 && $row['choosen']==1)
        {
            header("Location: notificationpage.php"); 
        }

    }
}
else
{
    header("Location:questions1.php"); 
}
```

**Solution:** Since every condition has predictable pattern, why don't we just put those pages into an associative array instead of creating tedious `if` conditions? Anyhow, this is my proposed adjustment to your code.

```
<?php

$locations = array(
    // Question Group ID => Landing page
    1 => 'people.php',
    2 => 'environment.php',
    3 => 'wideorganization.php',
    4 => 'procurement.php',
    5 => 'communication.php',
    6 => 'notificationpage.php'
);

if ($row['userid']==$user)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set))
    {
        // Here's the Question Group ID
        $questionGroupID = $row['question_group_id'];

        // Now we determine here
        if (isset($locations[$questionGroupID]) && $row['choosen'] == 1)
        {
            // Defined from the associative array above
            header(sprintf("location:%s", $locations[$questionGroupID]));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    header("location:questions1.php"); 
}
```

Now it's much easier to debug. Please try this code ;)

Comment: the code looks cleaner than mine..though when i run it am redirected to the first location people.php

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this code does its job :) If that always redirects you to `people.php`, that means the value of `question_group_id` column is 1. It will be more helpful for everyone to help you if you'll show the query you used and the structure of the source table from the database.

Comment: i am testing with a user who had done a survey for the first 3 the groups..so the person should be directed to procurement.php..lemme show the query and table structure

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code formatted without the loop and with a `switch` statement, as you requested. This might not work directly, because there are still too many uncertainties about the contents of `$newrow` and the origin of `$row`. But it's a great start and really good for debugging. The `switch` statement allows you to do some custom modifying per case (as you had before you editted your question).

```
$page = 'questions1.php';
if ($row['userid'] == $user):
    $newrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);
    if ($newrow['choosen'] == 1):
        switch ($newrow['question_group_id']):
            case 1:
                $page = 'people.php';
                break;
            case 2:
                $page = 'enviroment.php';
                break;
            case 3:
                $page = 'widerorganization.php';
                break;
            case 4:
                $page = 'procurement.php';
                break;
            case 5:
                $page = 'communication.php';
                break;
            case 6:
                $page = 'notificationpage.php';
                break;
        endswitch;
    endif;
endif;
header("Location: {$page}");
exit;
```